# 301 redirect all .htm to the root domain

Tags: http-status-code-301

I rebuilt a site and would like to redirect all urls ending in .htm (that might be in folders) to the root of the website.

I don't want to change or remove the extension, just make all the old adresses ending in .htm go to the root website [www.website.com/](http://www.website.com/)

I tried

`RedirectPermanent (.*)\.htm$ https://www.mywebsite.com` => does nothing

`RedirectMatch (.*)\.htm$ http://www.mywebsite.com` => "too many redirects"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the RedirectMatch rule.

```
RedirectMatch 302 \.htm$ /single-page
```

Comment: Edited .html to .htm

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a mod_rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /single-page [R=301,L]
```